# unable to run script on other pty - solaris

Tags: solaris, pty

When I am running a bash script on a different terminal , I see an error, bash command not found, whereas general commands work fine
my script reads input for a name and runs a query against a db and returns output 
OS solaris 
best regards
dpn

Comment: Is the `$PATH` environment variable set the same in both terminals?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try './scriptname' if you have not already tried this ?